# OOP Problems C++

Tags: c++

what is wrong? I think, it's correctly

```
class A{
public: 
    virtual bool isGun() = 0;
    virtual bool isArmor() = 0;
};

class B: public A{
public:
    virtual bool isGun(){ return true; }
};

int main(){
    B* b = new B;   
}
```

A::isArmor() - defined is other class

I realy need to define all pure virtual functions in all child-classes?

Comment: There is no `print` in your class definitions.

Comment: What makes you believe that `A::isGun()` is being called in your example, and not `B::isGun()`? How can `A::isGun()` even *be* called, when there's no definition for it?

Comment: And why do you believe `A::isGun()` gets called? That would be quite a trick, being able to call a pure, non-existent function.

Comment: I want to answer but you keep editing :) ! .. please make up your mind ... what is exactly the problem that you have ?

Comment: Each successive edit of this question makes it less and less comprehensible. Stick a fork in it, it's done.

Comment: You can't instantiate a `B` because `class B` doesn't define `isArmour()` which is *pure virtual*.

Comment: What is your actual question? And why do you `return 1;` in a `bool` function? If you're using `bool` stick to _boolean_ values.

Comment: @Aikon The least you could have done was provide the error message the compiler was giving you! It is extremely rude to expect others to help you and not put in the barest minimum of effort yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> what is wrong?

You haven't defined `isArmor` in `B` so you can't create any instances of `B`.

> I realy need to define all pure virtual functions in all child-classes?

Yes. That is what a pure virtual function *means*. If you don't want to have to define a function in all child-classes then don't make it pure virtual.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the pure virtual function in your subclass otherwise your subclass will become abstract class and hence we cannot create object of abstract class.

If you do not want isArmor function in subclass to expose, override it as private so that client of B cannot use it.

```
class B : public A{
private:
    virtual bool isArmor() { return true;  } // Like this
public:
    virtual bool isGun(){ return true; }
};
```